# Save data to mysql database in java

Tags: java, mysql

hello everyone i need your help.. i'm trying to save data to mysql database in java using netbeans IDE my source code doesn't want to run"it gives me an error that says"**Java.lang.NullPointerExcepion**

here's my source code..

```
try{
       String sql = "Insert into     clients(username,Id_number,surname,fullname,age,diagnose) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
       pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       pst.setString(1, txt_surname.getText());
       pst.setString(2, txt_fullname.getText());
       pst.setString(3, txt_age.getText());
       pst.setString(4, txt_diagnose.getText());
       pst.setString(5, txt_ID.getText());
       pst.setString(6, txtusername.getText());
       //pst.setString(7, txt_password.getText());

        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Saved");  
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);  
    }
```

Comment: On what line is the Exception thrown?

Comment: You should provie stackTrace, anyway check if `conn` or `pst` is null.. then check all this txt_*.

Comment: i don't know because it doesn't specify were the error come from

Comment: Add e.printStackTrace(); inside catch block

Comment: i don't know what to do now

Comment: Always log your stacktrace.

Comment: inside `catch(Exception e)` put this line: `e.printStackTrace();` then go to the console/terminal/idk everything and edit the question with the message

Comment: He's probably not getting the NPE inside the catch statement. He needs to go to the console where he's seeing the error in the first place and copy and paste the 15 lines above and below the error message, including the error message.

Comment: i included e.printStackTrace(); but still im getting the same error

Comment: @MarsAtomic what? The NPE is thrown inside the try. Because you should post here what your console printed out.

Comment: is there an alternative way i can use to save data on a database mysql  without using try and catch.. maybe that would minimize the problem

Answer (score 0):

This code is clear and ok. the only possible var causing trouble is con. So try to add a sysout print statement before all con == null and look if it is true, then check whats missing on the connection setup

Comment: this is how i connected  to the database                                          public static Connection ConnectDb()
{
    try{
        //Class.forName("conn.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/milton","root","" + "");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Well done!!! Connection Established");
        return conn;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry Connection Fail");
        return null;
    }
    
}